# Implementing security for users in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am after a better solution for security in Jenkins. After my play around this space, my current solution is to implement the 'Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy'. I was previously considering running Jenkins behind Apache and control security through Apache. But during my trial with matrix based security, I was able to assign full access to logged in users and block anonymous users from seeing anything on the dashboard except login-page.

Before I proceed with my beta servers, I would like to seek experts advice to understand what I am doing is correct ?or there is a better way to do this. At the moment I have around 30 users created in my system.

If matrix based solution is the best and easiest, I would like to know,
  1) Is it possible to group users and assign access based on groups ? So that I don't have to give users on individual basis

2) I also saw a post about 'Role strategy plug-in', but I couldn't see that in my Jenkins. Not sure if this plug-in out of date and/or nomore supported

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the [Role Strategy](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) plugin with a LDPA directory and it works well.

You just have to install this plugin on your Jenkins server and to switch from "Matrix-based security" to "Role-Based Strategy".

Next, you will be able to define roles:

[image]

And assign them to users (or LDAP groups, if you have a LDAP directory):

[image]

Comment: How about if I do not want to use LDAP ?

Comment: I think it's the same, you just affect the roles to your local users (instead of LDAP users or group).

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I will try this for sure. Have you found any drawbacks after using this model ? Just asking to understand if you had any issues or workarounds.

Comment: I'm working on a new staging environment (for my company). Before we were using the Jenkins user DB and the matrix based option. In the new environment, I've connected the new Jenkins server to our LDAP directory and I created the roles using the plugin above. For the moment, it's working well and I have no issues for the moment. If this solution works for you, please vote for the solution ;)

Comment: Thanks for your solution Bruno. I have not implemented that yet as the management is happy with the matrix based one at the moment. but I would consider your solution in near future. Thanks Again